# Add versionable & variantable models, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Running NodeJS on my server, I have some server-side business models (think of products, customers, widgets, documents etc). All of them can be stored in the DB. I want to be able to add to some of these models the following features:

- versionable
- variantable (nice to have)

**Versionable** - allows to manage the evolution of the Model’s object. For example if we apply it on my Products’ Model - I should be able:

- to know how *Product A* looked like at any specific time
- to work on a new version of *Product A* and to save it as a DRAFT and to be able to release the DRAFT so it becomes RELEASE and can start to work on a new DRAFT (the previous RELEASE will become Expired).
  [image]

**Variantable** (nice to have)  - allows to create branches (variants) from the main branch. Each branch is Versionable.
[image]

**The Question**: Is there any infrastructure (an existing npm module?) that implements this functionality?

For rails there is [BeRevisable](https://github.com/Natural-Intelligence/be_revisable) gem that implements the Versionable feature (can be added to any model by mixin) and may be also [acts_as_revisable](https://github.com/fatjam/acts_as_revisable) gem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [revisionist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/revisionist) and [revisions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/revisions).
They both provide simple solution you will need to extend but they are nice jump-start.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) Though to be able to effectively get a revision by date and also to mark revisions as LatestRelease and PrimaryDraft are essential for my needs.